# c++11 lock-free queue with 2 thread

Tags: multithreading, c++11, locking, lock-free

Along with the main thread, i have one more thread that receives data to write them in a file.

```
std::queue<std::vector<int>> dataQueue;
std::mutex mutex;

void setData(const std::vector<int>& data) {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
    dataQueue.push(data);
}

void write(const std::string& fileName) {
    std::unique_ptr<std::ostream> ofs = std::unique_ptr<std::ostream>(new zstr::ofstream(fileName));

    while (store) {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex);

        while (!dataQueue.empty()) {
            std::vector<int>& data= dataQueue.front();

            ofs->write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(data.data()), sizeof(data[0])*data.size());

            dataQueue.pop();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`setData` is used by the main thread and `write` is actually the writing thread. I use `std::lock_quard` to avoid memory conflict but when locking on the writing thread, it slows down the main thread as it has to wait for the Queue to be unlocked. But i guess i can avoid this as the threads never act on the same element of the queue at the same time.

So i would like to do it lock-free but i don't really understand how i should implement it. I mean, how can i do it without locking anything ? moreover, if the writing thread is faster than the main thread, the queue might be empty most of the time, so it should somehow waits for new data instead of looping infinitly to check for non empty queue.

**EDIT**: I changed simple `std::lock_guard` by `std::cond_variable` so that it could wait when the queue is empty. But the main thread can still be blocked as , when `cvQeue.wait(.)` is resolved, it reacquire the lock. moreover, what if the main thread does `cvQueue.notify_one()` but the writing thread is not waiting ?

```
std::queue<std::vector<int>> dataQueue;
std::mutex mutex;
std::condition_variable cvQueue;

void setData(const std::vector<int>& data) {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
    dataQueue.push(data);
    cvQueue.notify_one();
}

void write(const std::string& fileName) {
    std::unique_ptr<std::ostream> ofs = std::unique_ptr<std::ostream>(new zstr::ofstream(fileName));

    while (store) {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex);

        while (!dataQueue.empty()) {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
            cvQueue.wait(lock);

            ofs->write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(data.data()), sizeof(data[0])*data.size());

            dataQueue.pop();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could simply unlock around `write` call, and relock afterwards. You don't need to hold the lock while writing, which is likely the most time-consuming part of the loop.

Answer (score 2):

If you only have two threads, than you could use a lock-free single-producer-single-consumer (SPSC) queue.
A bounded version can be found here: https://github.com/rigtorp/SPSCQueue
Dmitry Vyukov presented an unbounded version here: http://www.1024cores.net/home/lock-free-algorithms/queues/unbounded-spsc-queue (You should note though, that this code should be adapted to use atomics.)

Regarding a blocking pop operation - this is something that lock-free data structures do not provide since such an operation is obviously not lock-free. However, it should be relatively straight forward to adapt the linked implementations in such a way, that a push operation notifies a condition variable if the queue was empty before the push.

Comment: I don't know whether it's a typo or the GitHub user changed their handle, but in any case, the correct SPSCQueue link is https://github.com/rigtorp/SPSCQueue . Note the addition of the "p" after "rigtor".
(There are currently too many pending edits on SO to allow me to edit the answer directly. Otherwise, I'd do that.)

Answer (score -1):

i guess i have something that met my needs. I did a `LockFreeQueue` that uses `std::atomic`. I can thus manage the state of the head/tail of the queue atomically.

```
template<typename T>
class LockFreeQueue {
public:
    void push(const T& newElement) {
        fifo.push(newElement);
        tail.fetch_add(1);
        cvQueue.notify_one();
    }

    void pop() {
        size_t oldTail = tail.load();
        size_t oldHead = head.load();

        if (oldTail == oldHead) {
            return;
        }

        fifo.pop();
        head.store(++oldHead);
    }

    bool isEmpty() {
        return head.load() == tail.load();
    }

    T& getFront() {
        return fifo.front();
    }

    void waitForNewElements() {
        if (tail.load() == head.load()) {
            std::mutex m;
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m);
            cvQueue.wait_for(lock, std::chrono::milliseconds(TIMEOUT_VALUE));
        }
    }

private:
    std::queue<T> fifo;
    std::atomic<size_t> head = { 0 };
    std::atomic<size_t> tail = { 0 };
    std::condition_variable cvQueue;
};

LockFreeQueue<std::vector<int>> dataQueue;
std::atomic<bool> store(true);

void setData(const std::vector<int>& data) {
    dataQueue.push(data);
    // do other things
}

void write(const std::string& fileName) {
    std::unique_ptr<std::ostream> ofs = std::unique_ptr<std::ostream>(new zstr::ofstream(fileName));

    while (store.load()) {

        dataQueue.waitForNewElements();

        while (!dataQueue.isEmpty()) {
            std::vector<int>& data= dataQueue.getFront();

            ofs->write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(data.data()), sizeof(data[0])*data.size());

            dataQueue.pop();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I still have one lock in `waitForNewElements` but it is not locking the whole process as it is waiting for things to do. But the big improvement is that the producer can push while the consumer pop. It is only forbidden when `LockFreQueue::tail` and `LockFreeQueue::head` are the same. Meaning that the queue is empty and it enters the waiting state.

The thing that i'm not very satisfied at is `cvQueue.wait_for(lock, TIMEOUT_VALUE)`. I wanted to do a simple `cvQueue.wait(lock)`, but the problem is that when it comes to end the thread, I do `store.store(false)` in the main thread. So if the writing thread is waiting it will never end without a timeout. So, I set a big enough timeout so that most of the time the `condition_variable` is resolved by the lock, and when the thread ends it is resolved by the timeout.

If you feel that something must be wrong or must be improved, feel free to comment.

Comment: [`std::queue`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue) isn't thread-safe.  You're not using any locking, but you're also not doing anything to make is safe when two threads run `fifo.push` and `fifo.pop` at the same time!  Maybe this happens to work for a `std::list` underlying container, especially with your atomic counters to stop you from running pop on an empty fifo I think is the purpose?  But in general it's not safe to use `std::queue` as a SPSC queue.

Comment: i don't get it. The push counter is increased after the push. So, the new element will "come alive" only when it is finished, insn' it ?

Comment: i maybe start to understand why it is not thread-safe. When there is one element in the queue, the producer may be starting to `push` a second one and the consumer start to `pop` just after. So the end of the `push` may be done on a different queue than it was at the start of the `push`. Is that so ?

Comment: Yes, that and none of the loads/stores are on `std::atomic` objects so its data-race UB for different threads to access them.  On x86, any asm the compiler generates will benefit from x86's strong memory model (where every load/store is acquire / release).  Weakly ordered ISAs might only need `mo_consume` on the read side which they do for free because of data dependency on a pointer they loaded, but the write side won't be using a release store to make sure that the last pointer-modification isn't visible until all the other data in a node is visible.

Comment: Writing a safe SPSC linked-list queue definitely takes *some* `atomic<>` operations, definitely to make it safely portable not just happens-to-work-sometimes-on-x86.  Your queue doesn't use any, except for the atomic counters outside the `std::queue` itself which you use with `seq_cst` order.  I'm pretty sure those aren't sufficient.

Comment: sorry, there should be some notion i don't know, because I don't understand why the atomic counters in `LockFreeQueue` wouldn't be enought as each pushed element do not "exist" untill the atomic counter is increased. Actually, I tried to do the implementation described here (the code is shown at 46 minutes) : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qdrp6k4rcP4 . Concerning my code, the difference is that i don't have a ring buffer, but a theoretically infinite queue. That is why i used `std::queue`.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list doesn't say it's thread-safe so you have to assume it isn't.  It does say that other iterators aren't invalidated by the operations you use, but that's not the same as thread-safe.  The `list<>` object itself has some pointers that push/pop will modify.  It might happen to be safe on some implementations, IDK.

Comment: got it. thanks for your time. i'll look for something more relevent.